# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI in Angular 2

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to post data to a web api with this structure:
`Ledger Header` and a `list of ledger details`. This is my class in the web api for the two:

```
public class PropertyLedgerDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int LedgerDetailID { get; set; }
    public int LedgerID { get; set; }
    public int? TransactionID { get; set; }
    public int? TransactionTypeID { get; set; }
    public double? Amount { get; set; }
    public double? PaymentAmount { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public bool Voided { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PostingDateTime { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyLeger
{
    [Key]
    public int LedgerID { get; set; }
    public int CollectingAgentID { get; set; }
    public int UnitID { get; set; }
    public int PaymentTypeID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(15)]
    public string ORNumber { get; set; }
    public int? VoidedLedgerID { get; set; }
    public bool? Voided { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TransactionDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PostingDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

and this is to combine the two classes so I can receive it from my frontend:

```
public class AddLedger
{
    public PropertyLeger PropertyLedger { get; set; }
    public List<PropertyLedgerDetail> PropertyLedgerDetails { get; set; }
}
```

In my Angular front end, this is how I set up the properties to send:

**Get values from 2 forms**

```
add() {
const PropertyLedgerModel: any = {
    CollectingAgentID: this.CollectingAgentID.value,
    UnitID: this.unitId,
    PaymentTypeID: this.PaymentTypeID.value,
    ORNumber: this.ORNumber.value,
    VoidedLedgerID: this.VoidedLedgerID.value,
    Voided: this.Voided.value,
    Remarks: this.Remarks0.value
}
const PropertyLedgerDetailsModel: any[] = this.dataSource;
const model: any = {
    PropertyLedger: PropertyLedgerModel,
    PropertyLedgerDetails: PropertyLedgerDetailsModel
}

this.pps.addLedger(model)
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
    debugger;
    if (data.StatusCode === 200) {
        this.ts.success(data.ReasonPhrase);
    } else {
        this.ts.error(data.ReasonPhrase);
    }
    },
err => {
    this.ts.error('An error has occured in saving payment(s): ' +err);
})
}
```

**To actually send this to the web api**

```
addLedger(model: any) {
    debugger;
    const ep = this.rootUrl + '/api/newpropertyledger';
    const PropertyLedgerModel: any = model.PropertyLedger;
    const PropertyLedgerDetailsModel: any [] = model.PropertyLedgerDetails;
    const Model: any = {
        PropertyLedger: PropertyLedgerModel,
        PropertyLedgerDetails: PropertyLedgerDetailsModel
    };
    return this.http.post(ep, Model);
}
```

I created a debug point on the part that will receive the data:
[image]

but the data from the front end doesn't reach the web api. I just get this error:

```
Message:"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:15232/api/newpropertyledger'."
MessageDetail:"No type was found that matches the controller named 'newpropertyledger'."
```

Please show me how to do it right. Thank you so much.

Comment: can you show me your WebApiConfig.cs please ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your api routing is correct i.e any of the api methods are getting hit,  this should help..

```
addLedger(model: any) {
    debugger;
    const ep = this.rootUrl + '/api/newpropertyledger';
    const PropertyLedgerModel: any = model.PropertyLedger;
    const PropertyLedgerDetailsModel: any [] = model.PropertyLedgerDetails;
    const Model: any = {
        PropertyLedger: PropertyLedgerModel,
        PropertyLedgerDetails: PropertyLedgerDetailsModel
    };
    return this.http.post(ep, JSON.stringify(ledger));
}

public HttpResponseMessage NewPropertyLedger(string data)
{
             AddLedger ledger = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddLedger>(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didn’t use your great suggestion  cause somehow, I found the solution just by copy and pasting the ‘api/newpropertyledger’ from my webapi to my frontend. I don’t know why it got corrected but it worked. If you will check in my post, you can see that there’s no difference in the routes and it doesn’t work but, cooy and pasting worked! I don’t know what’s up with that!

Comment: Thats fine but can you just test this and let me know